# How can I filter by specific date from realm object in swift?

Tags: swift, date, filter, realm

I have a realm object with date property type of Date , and want to get list of items with specific date.

If I click specific date from calendar, for example 2020-03-06 , then it will present list of items which was created in 2020-03-06.

*:: EDITED ::*

> Here is my realm object named "Profile" and there are dates from
>   2020-03-05 to 2020-03-08 .

[image]

> Here is my Profile object and ProfileManager Singleton.

```
class Profile: Object {
    @objc dynamic var date: Date!
    @objc dynamic var content: String!

    convenience init(_ content: String) {
        self.init()
        self.content = content
        self.date = Date()
    }
}


class ProfileManager {

    static let shared = ProfileManager()

    private var realm = try! Realm()

    var profileList: Results<Profile>?

    private init() {
        profileList = realm.objects(Profile.self)
    }

    func save(_ object: Profile) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func addNewProfile(_ content: String) {
        let newProfile = Profile(content)
        save(newProfile)
    }
}
```

> And lastly, here is a viewController which has to buttons. One for
>   adding new Profile, and one for printing filtered profile list.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func addProfilePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ProfileManager.shared.addNewProfile("profile content")
    }

    @IBAction func filterButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let stringDate = "2020-03-09"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let searchDate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
        let results = ProfileManager.shared.profileList!.filter("date == %@", searchDate)
        print(searchDate)
        print(results)
        for profile in results {
            print(profile.content!)
        }
    }
}
```

> the result on the console, when filterButtonPressed method called.

```
2020-03-08 15:00:00 +0000
Results<Profile> <0x7f9b36f160a0> (

)
```

How can I fix this problem?
And here is another problem.
I set to 'stringDate' a value of "2020-03-09"
but when I print converted date 'searchDate' , it prints "2020-03-08"
why this happens?

Hope now my questions is more clear to understand.

Comment: Post the code in the question please, not as image.

Comment: @Willeke OK, done.

Comment: I copy and pasted your edited code into a project and it worked correctly. However, please note you're searching for `let stringDate = "2020-03-09"` and that date with a day of **09** does not exist in the dataset shown in the question so there would be no results.

Comment: @Jay It's very strange that with same code, it works for you and doesn't work for me.. I know that there is no 09 day, I tried with any numbers and same result. And when I put number ,it prints day before from stringDate .in that case, it prints me 2020-03-08.. anyway want to fix this problem and no idea...

Comment: Hang on. I duplicated it. Let me get back to you.

Comment: @Jay Thank you.I'm on

Comment: I got it, updated the answer. Wow - that was crazy.

Comment: @Jay WOW. It is really crazy, I thought 'date == %@' means that if time in searchDate we put like "2020-03-08" contains in date property it should get items. but it should be the exact same from years to seconds.I'll have to store date as string because I need to filter items by dates in ascending  and I need time with seconds too.Thank you very very much for testing my code and answer. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer is below which, after a lot of research was only somewhat correct.

The actual answer has to do with the timestamp portion of the date.

So... if we create a date object using the below code and set it to a known date,

```
let stringDate = "2020-03-08"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let searchDate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
```

the actual object will look like this

```
2020-03-08T05:00:00.000Z
```

However, how the Profile object is being created is like this

```
convenience init(_ content: String) {
   self.init()
   self.content = content
   self.date = Date()
}
```

and that date object looks like this

```
2020-03-08T16:10:25.123Z
```

so as you can see, if we filter for a specific date these are not equal

```
2020-03-08T05:00:00.000Z != 2020-03-08T16:10:25.123Z
```

which is why this

```
let stringDate = "2020-03-08"
let searchDate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
let searchResults = realm.objects(Profile.self).filter("date == %@", searchDate)
```

could not find the date because it's filtering for this

```
2020-03-08T05:00:00.000Z
```

To fix, change the profile class with a date stamp with a default time stamp

```
class Profile: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date!
    @objc dynamic var content: String!

    convenience init(_ content: String) {
        self.init()
        self.content = content

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"

        let today = Date()
        let s = formatter.string(from: today)
        let d = formatter.date(from: s)

        self.date = d
    }
}
```

or, store your dates as a string yyyymmdd which will remove the ambiguity completely.

**-- ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW ---**

Filtering by date is fully supported on date objects. Here's two quick examples. One for filtering for a specific date (for your question) and one for a date range using BETWEEN.

Note, I have a function *makeDate* that casts a string to a date object. This example uses a Realm DogClass object that has a dog_birthdate Date property.

---

This filters for objects with a specific date

```
let searchDate = self.makeDate(fromString: "06/01/2019")
let specificDateResults = realm.objects(DogClass.self)
                               .filter("dog_birthdate == %@", searchDate)
for dog in specificDateResults {
    print(dog.dog_name)
}
```

---

This filters for objects within a date range

```
let startDate = self.makeDate(fromString: "06/01/2019")
let endDate = self.makeDate(fromString: "06/20/2019")
let dateRangeResuls = realm.objects(DogClass.self)
                           .filter("dog_birthdate BETWEEN {%@,%@}", startDate, endDate)
for dog in dateRangeResuls {
    print(dog.dog_name)
}
```

**EDIT**: Using the code in the comment from the OP for testing

```
let stringDate = "2019-06-01"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let searchDate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
let result = realm.objects(DogClass.self).filter("dog_birthdate == %@", searchDate)
for dog in result {
    print(dog.dog_name)
}
```

which works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I tried to test like code below and print this list ,    
   let stringDate = "2020-03-07"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let searchDate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
        realm.objects(T.self).filter("date == %@", searchDate)

but it shows me an empty list.  

Results<Card> <0x7f840643aec0> (

)

Comment: @alphonse Please see the edit to my answer. I copy and pasted the code in your comment into my project, changed the field in your comment from `date` to `dog_birthdate` to match my objects structure and added `let result = realm...`. It works correctly with those changes. Oh, and removed `T.self` as I don't know what `T` is and substituted my DogClass name

Comment: It's very wired that I tested with another realm object property called "content" which type is String. there is an item which contains string "Banana". and realm.objects(T.self).filter("content == %@", "Banana") with this code, it show me item with Banana .But why it doesn't work with date type?

Comment: @alphonse I don't know as the code from your comment is working for me as shown in my answer. I noticed someone voted to close your question - probably because it doesn't contain any code. Perhaps you can update your question with your Realm model and the code you're currently using - it's working for me so you must be doing something different and it's easier to examine the code in the question than in comments.

Comment: Yes I think there is something wrong with my realm object. I'll try to fix it. thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please see my edited question again? I tried to create new object from scratch but couldn't find what is wrong.